# Make requested BTC price a variable

Tags: python, json, variables, python-requests, bitcoin

Using the MtGox API I got the USD price for BTC. But how do I make it into a variable?

```
url = 'http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})
print (r.json()['data']['avg']['display_short'])
```

I am not familiar with json and just recently installed the requests module to do this.

Comment: Does this print the value you expect? If so, just assign the thing you’re `print`ing to a variable.

Comment: Doing this prints `None` when calling the variable.

Comment: Why don’t you post the code you’re trying to use for that.

Comment: Simply put, I want to convert a BTC amount to USD.

Comment: you can also use [forex-python](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python) to get bit coin rates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. All you have to do is:

```
x = r.json()['data']['avg']['display_short']
```